# How to stop infinite slider on thumbnail image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got codes for thumbnail slider from menu cool but the slider won't stop at a point where it ends, it is infinite.You can find [here](http://www.menucool.com/slider/jquery-slideshow). Please help.

Comment: Can we see what you have already tried ?

Comment: @Hearner I tried but I didn't know where to begin.

Comment: Is it a bird ? Is it a plane ? Nah, it's @JohnMcClane ! More seriously, please, provide the code you wrote and be more specific on your question. Read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will help you a lot for your nexts questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will change showMode setting to 1, then it will not be stuck in infinite scroll

```
var thumbnailSliderOptions =
{
    sliderId: "thumbnail-slider",
    orientation: "horizontal",
    thumbWidth: "300px",
    thumbHeight: "150px",
    showMode: 1,  // earlier this was set to 3 change it to 1
    infiniteSlides: false,
    stopAtEnd: true,
    autoAdvance: false,
    selectable: true,
    slideInterval: 3000,
    transitionSpeed: 1000,
    shuffle: false,
    startSlideIndex: 0, //0-based
    pauseOnHover: true,
    initSliderByCallingInitFunc: false,
    rightGap: "default",
    keyboardNav: true,
    mousewheelNav: true,
    before: null,
    license: "b2e98"
};
```